# How to pass data from ASP.NET View to React component in ReactJS.NET

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, reactjs.net

I'm trying out [ReactJS.NET](https://reactjs.net/) in a .NET Core MVC project where I've got an ASP.NET View (cshtml) with a React component in it, which I initialize with:

```html
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myComponent.jsx")"></script>
```

Now I want to pass data from the ASP.NET View to the React component. For example, calling a React function when I click a button on the ASP.NET View. Is this possible? I know it's a basic question but I couldn't find any help since in all examples the data is only passed between React components and not from outside (ASP.NET View).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do what I described in this question. So I ended up coding the whole page in ReactJS, which took some time to get into but it worked out well and I didn't have to mix technologies.

Comment: Although you already gave up on the original question, it's kind of OT but as not everyone has noticed it, it should be mentioned that ReactJS.NET is unfortunately in the process of dying. The author and maintainer has left the following [notice](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/1315).

Answer (score 0):

Declare a JS variable in a script and assign a property value from the Model:

```
<script type="text/javascript">let modelProperty= '@Model.ModelProperty';</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myComponent.jsx")"></script>
```

Then use that *modelProperty* in your ReactJS script:

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent prop0={modelProperty} />, document.getElementById("yourTargetElementId"))
```

Maybe there are more neat solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the nature of the data , you could try localStorage or sessionStorage. You could also try use route parameters (or url parameters) to support your use case.

If it's sensitive/private data you can encrypt the data you put in sessionStorage ... if its NOT sensitive or complex data then url parameters or route parameters would work.

Session or localStorage are best for a lot of structured data such as a large JSON object.

Strictly speaking (given your concept) the url parameters solutions are "passing" data whereas session storage is holding data for collection .

Either way you share the data between different server page types hosted from the same web application.